# Chrome omnibox querystring breaks, replaces my '?' with '%3F'

Tags: google-chrome, encoding, omnibox

I have a local html file, with embedded javascript, that I use query parameters with to modify the functionality. previously, it worked fine, and in fact, i have bookmarked pages which work fine when i click on the bookmark.

The problem occurs when I try to enter in a url with the query string in the chrome omnibox. it replaces my '?' '%3F' and the whole thing breaks because it can't even read the file, as it thinks the file extension is now '.html%3FfirstParam=firstValue&secondParam... etc.'

I'm not really sure how to approach this problem. my app can be found here, if you need clarification, but i think it has more to do with Chrome. https://youtu.be/1BHMyZkDkxA

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to get it to work if I manually added the "file://" to the beginning, and made sure that the ".html" was followed by a "?"